# recursive javascript function to return detail

Tags: javascript, recursion

So, I built a JavaScript array of objects like this

```
var menu = [
    {id:1 , parent:0 , name: 'home'},
    {id:2 , parent:0 , name: 'about'},
    {id:3 , parent:0 , name: 'products'},
    {id:4 , parent:3 , name: 'latest products'},
    {id:5 , parent:0 , name: 'news'},
    {id:6 , parent:0 , name: 'contacts'},
    {id:7 , parent:3 , name: 'archive products'},
    {id:8 , parent:5 , name: 'arch news'},
    {id:9 , parent:7 , name: 'search archive'}
];
```

and I built a recursive function to make a tree from that array like this:

```
function makeTree(menu,parent){
    var node ={};
    menu.filter(function (c) {
             return c.parent ===parent
        })
        .forEach(function(c) {
            node[c.id] = makeTree(menu,c.id)
            return
        });
    return (node)
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(makeTree(menu,0),null,3));
```

the function works perfect, and returns this result as expected:

```
{
   "1": {},
   "2": {},
   "3": {
      "4": {},
      "7": {
         "9": {}
      }
   },
   "5": {
      "8": {}
   },
   "6": {}
}
```

Now, here's my question:

As you can see the returned object has only id, how can I include the name in my return as well, something like this:

```
{
       "1": {name:"home"},
       "2": {name:"about"},.....
```

Comment: You can define in each node two properties, such as `children` and `data`

Answer (score 2):

so you need to store both name and children..

```
function makeTree(menu,parent){
    var node = {name:menu.name,children:{}};
    menu.filter(function (c) {
             return c.parent ===parent
        })
        .forEach(function(c) {
            node.children[c.id] = {
               name: c.name,
               children: makeTree(menu,c.id)
            }
            return
        });
    return (node)
}
```

will give you this

```
{
   "children": {
      "1": {
         "name": "home",
         "children": {
            "children": {}
         }
      },
      "2": {
         "name": "about",
         "children": {
            "children": {}
         }
      },
      "3": {
         "name": "products",
         "children": {
            "children": {
               "4": {
                  "name": "latest products",
                  "children": {
                     "children": {}
                  }
               },
               "7": {
                  "name": "archive products",
                  "children": {
                     "children": {
                        "9": {
                           "name": "search archive",
                           "children": {
                              "children": {}
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "5": {
         "name": "news",
         "children": {
            "children": {
               "8": {
                  "name": "arch news",
                  "children": {
                     "children": {}
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "6": {
         "name": "contacts",
         "children": {
            "children": {}
         }
      }
   }
}
```